# PHP startup issue on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with Apache and PHP 7.2. Everything works fine. My queries are working fine, but now and then I get error report with following description

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats))
```

I tried to search for it in php.ini but I can't find the problem. I tried to google it, but I can't find the same problem.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing it and how can I stop it?

Result from grep[image]

Comment: No. That is solution for windows. I need a solution for linux.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install php-mysql` in your terminal

Comment: did you comment `extension=php_mysqli.dll` if did un comment that line i got same problem once

Comment: There is no .dll on linux!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have php-mysql installed. To install that, open terminal and run this command:

```
sudo apt install php-mysql
```

after that you need to restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

You can check whether mysqli installed or not with this command line:

```
php -i | grep mysqli
```

Comment: Yes, I have php-mysql installed! Also mysqli and pdo! Please, read my post!

Comment: @Budimir Cannot find that on your question but seems you didn't install php-mysql. `php-mysql` is different from `php` and `mysql`. Please check your `mysqli` status with `phpinfo()` or `php -i | grep mysqli`. and add the result to your question.

Comment: I have added a printscreen from grep.

Comment: @Budimir `sudo apt remove php* apache* mysql*` and `sudo apt purge php* apache* libapache2-mod-php* mysql*` to remove all of them. install it again with `sudo apt install php php-mysql mysql-client apache2 libapache2-mod-php`

Comment: @ICE This solution worked for me it deserves a thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I solved changing php.ini

from:

```
extension=mysqli
```

to:

```
;extension=mysqli
```

because all mysqli settings already are here:

```
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
```